# what kind of submeter in terms of amperage should I get

Tags: mains

I need to install a submeter for a tenant who has 3 chillers (610 watts @ 220 volts) and some LED lights only.  I see some submeters that are rated 30 amps and 60 amps? What submeter size should I get?

Comment: Device consume 3A. You need may be 10A.

Comment: Hi user263983. That means a 30amp submeter would be sufficient?  what advantages or disadvantages if I were to get the 60 amp submeter which cost just 1 dollar more?

Comment: What is feeder capacity? How many amperes you can get? Smaller range you get better accuracy? Niger range you may have spare for  future use. If breaker on electrical panel rated for 15 A , 30 A is too much.

Comment: feeder capacity is  most likely 100amps. What do you mean better accuracy? do you mean that I will get a different reading for the 30amp and 60 amp submeter?

Comment: You don't give the full picture of electrical power distribution. If you have subpanel for tenants with feeder 100A and install meter before main breaker of what subpanel,  100A meter required. If you set meter after 30A breaker,  30A meter is enough. Accuracy mean the measurement divided by small steps. Quantity of steps   is same in both meters but 30A has smaller step that 60A.

Comment: Thank you user263983 for your inputs. I will just install a 30amps submeter .

Answer (score 1):

what size fuse or breaker comes before the location where the submeter will go?

You should a meter that meets or exceeds the amperage of the fuse or breaker feeding it.

Comment: the breaker size would be around 30 amps only.

Comment: by the way, do I install the submeter before or after the 30amp breaker?